# For Each...Next statement not behaving as expected

Tags: excel, vba

I have several worksheets with various financial quotes on certain rows with up to four of these rows containing a tick (Marlett font letter 'a' trick). My VBA code is meant to identify the ticked rows and transfer these rows only to another summary worksheet.

The problem is that my code is looping through the range and copying rows but not always the ticked ones and often duplicating them. It is hard to summarise concisely and is better to open up the excel workbook with some data in place (which I have anonymised so as not to disclose any personal data).

I have been helped with simplifying my original code on this forum and it is that poster's code I have pasted below (which I am very grateful for too btw!).

```
Private Sub CopyRows()

Dim cel2 As Range

ScreenUpdating = False

With Sheets("QChecklist1")
    For Each Cell In .Range("E8:E30")
        If Cell.Value = "a" Then
            Set cel2 = Sheets("QAnalysisForm").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
            Rows(Cell.Row).Resize(, 10).Offset(, 1).Copy cel2
            cel2.Value = cel2.Value
            Set cel2 = Nothing
        End If
    Next
End With

With Sheets("QChecklist2")
    For Each Cell In .Range("E8:E30")
        If Cell.Value = "a" Then
            Set cel2 = Sheets("QAnalysisForm").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
            Rows(Cell.Row).Resize(, 10).Offset(, 1).Copy cel2
            cel2.Value = cel2.Value
            Set cel2 = Nothing
        End If
    Next
End With

With Sheets("QChecklist3")
    For Each Cell In .Range("E8:E30")
        If Cell.Value = "a" Then
            Set cel2 = Sheets("QAnalysisForm").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
            Rows(Cell.Row).Resize(, 10).Offset(, 1).Copy cel2
            cel2.Value = cel2.Value
            Set cel2 = Nothing
        End If
    Next
End With

With Sheets("QChecklist4")
    For Each Cell In .Range("E8:E30")
        If Cell.Value = "a" Then
            Set cel2 = Sheets("QAnalysisForm").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
            Rows(Cell.Row).Resize(, 10).Offset(, 1).Copy cel2
            cel2.Value = cel2.Value
            Set cel2 = Nothing
        End If
    Next
End With

Sheets("QAnalysisForm").Activate
cells(1, 1).Select

On Error Resume Next


ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

I was expecting this code to search through each range on each 
'QChecklist' worksheet looking for 'ticked' rows (which are Marlett font 
a's) and copy and paste it to the QAnalysisForm worksheet.

What actually happens I will upload an image of but essentially:

It finds (in the case of QChecklist1) the four ticked rows, then repeats 
the second and fourth one, then repeats the entire four rows twice more! 
In total I get 14 rows instead of the 4 desired! On other QChecklist 
worksheets (i.e. QChecklists 2, 3 & 4 that I have coded for) I get 
similar patterns of repeating.

I also expected to have the ticked rows transferred from all QChecklist 
worksheets into the one QAnalysis (summary of best quotes) worksheet but 
instead the code only lifts the rows from the worksheet that contains the 
macro command button. I can live with it needing to be fired on each worksheet seperately as mostly there is only one or two worksheets normally but in my sample test case there are four seperate worksheets.

Image of Repeating Rows Link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/rltdbjcui3q6843/Image%20of%20Repeating%20Rows.png?dl=0

Excel Workbook containing Quotation Analysis Worksheets:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/3bxxxs54cruyqi2/QuotationAnalysisSystemBeta.xlsm?dl=0

Comment: The first thing that strikes me is `Rows` will refer to the Active sheet.  Did you meant to use `.Rows` which will refer to the sheet you reference in with `With`?

Comment: @Gareth - Post it as an answer, I tested it and it seems to have worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Rows` refers to the ActiveSheet.  To use the "`With`" sheet use `.Rows`

You are also making a bit of extra work for yourself by having the same code four times.  This means you have to make the same change in multiple places running the risk of errors.

There are a few ways to solve this but a simple sub is the easiest in this case.

```
Private Sub CopyRows()
    ScreenUpdating = False

    doWork Sheets("QChecklist1")
    doWork Sheets("QChecklist2")
    doWork Sheets("QChecklist3")
    doWork Sheets("QChecklist4")

    Sheets("QAnalysisForm").Activate
    Cells(1, 1).Select

    On Error Resume Next

    ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Private Sub doWork(sht As Worksheet)
    Dim cel2 As Range
    With sht
        For Each Cell In .Range("E8:E30")
            If Cell.Value = "a" Then
                Set cel2 = Sheets("QAnalysisForm").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                .Rows(Cell.Row).Resize(, 10).Offset(, 1).Copy cel2
                cel2.Value = cel2.Value
                Set cel2 = Nothing
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Gareth, thanks very much for the distinction between Rows vs .Rows. Also with nesting the For Each inside the With and passing the sht variable as an argument in the doWork function.

Comment: Hi @gareth just tested. That works a treat! I get why things work with that code but baffled why when my original code was used it actually did loop over and over using Rows but constructing it a little different and using .Rows the duplication stops. If it was obvious why it looped originally you probably would've explained and regardless I am very grateful for the solution.